# Postgresql/JDBC fails with or without UTF8 encoding

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, encoding

Using Java 8 and a Postgres 10 Server, and the v 42.2.16 Postgresql Driver,
I have a basic JDBC query function:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> Query(String sql) throws Exception {
    Connection con = null ;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetToList = null;
    try {
        
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString, Properties);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement( sql );
        pstmt.execute();
        
        ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.getResultSet();
        resultSetToList = resultSetToList(resultSet);

        pstmt.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
        finally {
    
        if (con != null)
            con.close();
    }
    return resultSetToList;
}
```

I execute a query like this:

```
Query("SELECT * FROM bi_functions");
```

But it throws an Exception

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3

The database (provided by 3rd party) has encoding `SQL_ASCII`. 0xA3 is the 'British Pound' character.

So I change the query to:

```
SET LOCAL CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'SQL_ASCII'; SELECT * FROM bi_functions;
```

It fails with:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server's client_encoding parameter was changed to SQL_ASCII. The JDBC driver requires client_encoding to be UTF8 for correct operation.

Is there a way **using plain JDBC** to circumvent this error?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The interesting question is: what is the server encoding, and what bytes are stored in the database?

Comment: DB (provided by 3rd party) has encoding SQL_ASCII.  0xA3 is the 'British Pound' character.  Are you saying I can't read this DB via JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses a Unicode encoding internally, so you cannot use a `client_encoding` different from `UTF8` with the JDBC driver.

You should figure out the actual encoding of the database (probably one of the ISO 8859 or a Windows encoding). Then create a database with that encoding and dump the original database and load your dumped database into it.

Otherwise you won't be able to use this database with JDBC.

Comment: On the 3rd party server, the DB is listed as Encoding SQL_ASCII; Collation en_GB; Character Type en_GB.  Is there another way to determine the "actual encoding" ?  It's a Windows server, so probably 1252 encoding.  If I create a DB locally with that encoding, won't I encounter the same issue when querying it via JDBC?

Comment: If all the data in the database are consistent with Windows-1252, you won't have a problem. If they are not (say, some UTF-8 data have sneaked in), you'll have to repair the data in the database.

Comment: I'm restoring the DB on a Mac (Catalina) server -does that make a difference?

Comment: No, the platform shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: restoring the backup to a DB created with ENCODING = 'WIN1252' worked, thanks